# load li class active to bootstrap nav loaded dynamically to an html page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap navbar loaded dynamically to an html page via script

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#nav-placeholder").load("menu.html");
  });      
</script>
```

it loads perfect!, what I need now is to set the class="active"

this is my menu.html loaded into let's say our mision page

```
<div class="container navbar-fixed-top">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img alt="Brand" src="media/35px_carinhands_logo2.png">
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="our.html">our mision</a></li>
            <li><a href="ser.html">services</a></li>
            <li><a href="why.html">why us</a></li>
            <li><a href="fee.html">fees</a></li>
            <li><a href="faq.html">faq</a></li>
            <li><a href="contacto.html">contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
            <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>
            <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-instagram" href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></a>

        </div>
     </div>
</nav>
```

what I want is when menu is loaded in "our.html" `<li><a href="our.html">our mision</a></li>` li goes `<li class="active"><a href="our.html">our mision</a></li>`

this is what I've tried:

```
 <!-- Navigation -->    
 <script>
  $(function(){
    $("#nav-placeholder").load("menu.html");
  });      
</script>
```

I add the place holder into body

```
<div id="nav-placeholder"></div>
```

then I try to call the class

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active").find("li:nth-child(1)").addClass("active");
});</script>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We expect you to show us what you already tried to solve the problem, what your research has lead to - or at least give a concrete, specific problem description.

Comment: I would look at using a promise object to add that class when the loading of your nav-bar resolves. The easy solution would be to just add the class "active" in the html of your menu.html

Comment: (Im new, trying to figure out how to post a readable code

Comment: thank you @CBore this is what I tried

`<body>
     <!-- Navigation -->    
     <script>
      $(function(){
        $("#nav-placeholder").load("menu.html");
      });      
    </script>

<div id="nav-placeholder"></div>

<script>
  $ (document) .ready (function(){
      $("#nav-placeholder").find("li:nth-child(our mision)").addClass("active");
      });
</script>`

Comment: thank you @Ryan Wilson
 the problem is that,  if I do manually, In this case I just have 6 items but, imagine I have more, that's why I loaded the menu dynamically.

if I set this manually, then I should cut and paste in each html page the nav bar and that's not the goal

Comment: `.find("li:nth-child(our mision)")` - that is not how `:nth-child` works, you can not supply a “search term”. To select elements based on text content, you could use https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ But since you want to automate this, it would make more sense to find the link with the matching `href` attribute content - because then you can compare this with the current page address from the `location` object.

Comment: @Cbore Ok. should I add the script into the html were the menu will be loaded or into menu.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted my old answer and edit your code litle. I hope this help.

```
<!-- Navigation -->    
 <script>
  $(function(){
    $("#nav-placeholder").load("menu.html", function() {
    //wait for ajax load n add active class
        //$(".navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active").find("li:nth-child(1)").addClass("active");
    $('a[href="' + decodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '')) + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
    });
  });      
</script>
```

Comment: HI... no, not working see it here (just in case [link](http://www.juansebastianblanco.com/chdemo/our.html) it should highlight the "Our Mision" Tab in White Background and blur text

Comment: Not working because pages not on root replace with this. I tested it is working.
$('a[href="' + decodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname.replace('/chdemo','').replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '')) + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

Comment: yes the menu loads like it was but the active tab does not shows :(. and that's the goal any clue?

Comment: I think I've done it modifying a bit your code!, will test in remote and let you know

Comment: you have put this code to all pages or create a script like app.js add the code and include to all pages

Comment: `<!-- Navigation -->    
     <script>
      $(function(){
        $("#nav-placeholder").load("menu.html", function() {
          $("ul.nav.navbar-nav").find("li:nth-child(1)").addClass("active");
          });
      });      
    </script>`

this is what worked out. As you said I must add this in all page (changing the li child element number ).

I know ther must be a better efficient way to do it but hits worked just fine for this small project. THANK YOU! :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't mark it, and sorry this can't be a chat too because Im new and dont have some privileges.

I did not mark it as correct cause worked partial to yours however I can edit or you can edit to the one who solved my problem, I gladly will mark it as I can't mark my own answer yet

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked out.

add this code in all page (changing the li child element number) or link the .js in the correct page

```
 <!-- Navigation -->    
 <script>
  $(function(){
    $("#nav-placeholder").load("menu.html", function() {
      $("ul.nav.navbar-nav").find("li:nth-child(1)").addClass("active");
      });
  });      
</script>
```

thank you @Mustafa Çetin for that light in the sea